# How to prove a polynominal is irreducible over GF(2)?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

How do you prove a polynomial is irreducible over GF(2)?

Comment: Can you add some context please? There is of course a 'reasonable' algorithm, but what do you want/need?

Comment: I need to prove a polynominal of degree n is irreducible over GF(2). For example, I know x^4 + x + 1 is an irreducible polynominal of degree 4, but how do I prove it?

Comment: For $x^4+x+1$: It cant have a linear factor, because then it would have a root. But $x=0$ and $x=1$ are not solutions. If $x^4+x+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$, then $b=d=1$. But then $a+c=1$ equating the linear terms, and also $a+c=0$ equating the terms of degree $3$. So, no factorization in $GF(2)$ into polynomials of smaller degree.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general  result for all finite fields:

> Let $\mathbf F_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements ($q=p^r$ for some prime $p$). In $\mathbf F_q[X]$, the polynomial $X^{q^n}-X$ is the product of all irreducible monic polynomials of degree dividing $n$

As a consequence, in  $\mathbf F_q[X]$, there exist s irreducible polynomials of every degree.

One also deduces the

> *Irreducibility criterion*: A polynomial $P\in\mathbf F_q[X]$ with degree $n$ is irreducible if  and only if
>
> 1. $P$ divides $X^{q^n}-X$;
> 2. $P$ is coprime with all  $X^{q^r}-X$, $\;r=\dfrac nd$, where $d$ is a prime divisor of $n$.

Comment: So for a polynominal of degree 4 (x^4+x+1) and GF(2), I would divide (x^2^4 - x) by (x^4+x+1)? For criteria 2, what do you mean by "d is a prime divisor of n"?

Comment: Yes. It amounts to Euclid's algorithm (which is especially simple over $\mathbf F_2$).

Comment: So for criteria 2. If n = 4, the prime divisor is just 2. Therefore, I would test GCD(x^4+x+1, x^2^(4/2) - x)?

Comment: Exactly. As $X^4-X=X(X+1)(X^2+X+1)$, this shouldn't be too long…

Comment: I put (x^2^4 - x)/(x^4+x+1) into matlab, and I got a really long polynomial with a remainder: Quotient = x^12 - x^9 - x^8 + x^6 + 2*x^5 + x^4 - x^3 - 3*x^2 - 3*x. Remainder = 4*x^3 + 6*x^2 + 2*x. I assume this means it passes Criteria 1?

Comment: I don't get something. The polynomial x^4 + 1 IS reducible over GF(2), but it passes both criteria of irreducibility. (x^4+1) divides (X^16 - x) & GCD([x^4+1], [x^4-x]) = 1...

Comment: Not at all: $\gcd(x^4+1,x^4-x)=x+1$.

Comment: Matlab is giving me 1 though

Comment: Various online calculators like WolframAlpha are also giving me GCD(x^4+1, x^4-x) = 1. How did you get x+1?

Comment: By hand: $X^4+1=(X+1)^4$ and $X^4+X=X(X^3+1)=X(X+1)(X^2+X+1)$ are the decompositions into irreducible factors (don't forget the characteristic is $2$). Did you specify all this was on  $\mathbf F_2$?

Comment: yes, it is over GF(2). Am I missing something here? $(X+1)^4 = x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 1$

Comment: $4=6=0$ over $\mathbf F_2$. Exponent $4$ is just the iterated Frobenius autmorphism. The problem is: does Wolfram Alpha know it is over  $\mathbf F_2$?